# Does chrome cache bootstrap css?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am going to change this but when i started a project I change one of the color settings in bootstrap.

When I ran my site in debug from visual studio everything looked as expect.

I have now published to a server (first time) but yet the color change I made in the bootstrap.css is not showing.  If I inspect the element in chrome it shows as the standard bootstrap setting not what I have changed?

looking at the network tab in chrome it shows that a lot of this is "cached from disk"?

[image]

I know it says cached from disk there and it may sound a stupid question, but what I don't understand is that it is a new server so there would be nothing to cached, yet it seems to be using some "cached" css style instead of the one I have published?

again in the netwrok tab of the chrome debug, for the bootstrap line above, under header it has

> Cache-Control:public

not sure what that means in terms of loading it

Comment: I understand it is say cached there, but I mentioned I published this for the first time and it was different.  How can it have cached that when there was nothing published there to cache before?

Answer (score 3):

You can reload the cache to see if it works. Push F12 on Windows (On Mac: Cmd+Opt+I) then you can right click on refresh and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' to reload the cache.

[image]

Comment: under the application tab clear site data?

can't find a refresh to right click?

Comment: tried that option but still no change, has he standard bootstrap.css color.

loaded it on my mobile, first time ever... but uses standard bootstra.css also

Comment: Maybe the bootstrap file is not loaded ? Take a look into the console

Comment: If you hit F12 an then look at the "Sources" tab do you see your css file ? Also try to find it on the "Network" tab, if you cannot find it there it means it is not loaded.

Comment: Is the server hosted somewhere or your own local? If hosted, does the host cache files (which they might)? If local, what are your settings for the server regarding caching?

Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/600101.

Comment: Yeah it is hosted.  I'll have to look into caching settings to be honest.. this isn't really my strongest area so still learning as I go along! will read that article thanks.

For now I have reverted my bootstrap file to the latest version and then added my own classes to the DOM for the effects I needed which is probably what I should have done in the first place.